# Vaadin TextField suffixComponent with multiple icons

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to use the vaadin [TextField](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/text-field) Prefix & Suffix component feature with multiple icons, but when I wrap the multiple icons in a `div` or `span` some styling changes that makes the icons change size (gets enlarged slightly).

For instance the following code:

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.setPrefixComponent(VaadinIcon.CLIPBOARD_TEXT.create());
tf.setSuffixComponent(new Span(VaadinIcon.CLIPBOARD_TEXT.create(), VaadinIcon.LINK.create()));
```

Generates a text field that looks like:
[image: prefix looks good but suffix gets enlarged]

This is on vadin 24.1 where I just took the output generated from start.vaadin.com and adjusted the textbox.

Any hints to how I can get the default styling when wrapping multiple icons in a container?

Comment: Can you tray to use a VerticalLayout instead of a Span

Comment: I did try using a HorizontalLayout and the result was even larger icons (VerticalLayout stacks them on top of each other).

Comment: In that case you have to set the size of the icons

Comment: Ok, so I did som browser Developer Tools inspection and ended up figuring out that what makes the 'small' icon smaller is the following style: `padding: 0.25em`, I will answer my own question shortly with complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after inspection the browser console and comparing the styles applied it became clear that the small version of the icon was due to it having `padding: 0.25em`.

I created a TextFieldBuilder where I keep the icons in a list, then I use the following code to apply the icons to the text field:

```
if (icons.size() == 1) {
    tf.setSuffixComponent(icons.get(0));
} else if (icons.size() > 1) {
    // work around vaadin styling issue by manually adding some padding if we have multiple icons
    icons.forEach(i -> i.getStyle().set("padding", "0.25em"));
    tf.setSuffixComponent(new Span(icons.toArray(Icon[]::new)));
}
```

I'm not 100% satisfied since I think there is a little too much space between the icons. I did try with individual left/right/top/bottom padding but I was not able to get it any better than this.

It now looks like:

[image: somehwat fixed styling]